# Facebook login in unity iOS game without redirect

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine

In my game I use for login in Facebook

```
FB.Login("email,publish_actions,user_games_activity", LoginCallback);
```

When I click on button, Safari browser pops up for a second and then redirects me back to my app without connecting me to Facebook. I need without redirect authorization and popups

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

1) Locating Facebook/Editor/iOS/FbUnityInterface.mm

2) Find method -(void)login:(const char *)scope { ... }

3) change

```
openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView
```

to

```
openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
```

4) now, each time you request login, an embed web-view dialog will be popped out instead of jumping out of current game to Facebook login dialog.